# Adding event listener for lit element component inside typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, lit-element

I've successfully added an eventlistener for my Lit element component inside my Typescript code:

```
async firstUpdated() {
  await this.updateComplete;

  // Add an event listener to our event-search component so we can switch the current event
  const eventSearch = document.querySelector('event-search');
  if(typeof eventSearch !== 'undefined') {
    eventSearch.addEventListener('select', this.changeCurrentEvent);
  }
}

async changeCurrentEvent(event) {
  await this.fetchTickets(event.id);
  this.currentEvent = event;
}

async fetchTickets(eventId: number) {
  try {
    this.tickets = await fetchData(ticketEndpoint(eventId))
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

However, when executing the event i get the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.fetchTickets is not a function at HTMLElement.<anonymous>`

Apparently it does land in the `changeCurrentEvent` function but it cannot find the `fetchTickets` function.

Comment: by the time `changeCurrentEvent` gets executed, `this` context is being lost. Can you try with `eventSearch.addEventListener('select', this.changeCurrentEvent.bind(this))`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not [binding the event listener in your template](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events#where-to-add-your-event-listeners), e.g. `<event-search @select=${this.changeCurrentEvent}>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ES6 Arrow Function syntax to avoid having to write `this.changeCurrentEvent.bind(this)`.

```
changeCurrentEvent = async (event) => {
  await this.fetchTickets(event.id);
  this.currentEvent = event;
}
```